# Can't Get Gridview Row data from RowIndex

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I am stuck in one problem and I hope you guys will help me to get this thing done.

I have a web application with update panel implemented in it. I have a Grid View which is placed inside the update panel. In Grid View there is a template filed of Text Box with Auto PostBack="true". On Text Changed event i want to get that row data on server side.

Grid View is Bind with data on Page Load event and after every one minute when timer ticks.

The problem I am facing is that on server side I get the row data as null. The code may help you guys.

Aspx page

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="c-table">
          <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="100" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
                  <Columns>

                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                    <p> <%# Eval("Id") %></p>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:TemplateField>

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                    <p> <%# Eval("Title") %></p>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bid">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>

               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link">
               <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
               </EditItemTemplate>
               <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server"  CommandName="visit" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("id") %>'>Visit</asp:LinkButton>  
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>


               </Columns>

               </asp:GridView>



              </ContentTemplate>
             </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.cs code

```
    protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        GridViewRow gridRow = ((GridViewRow)((TextBox)sender).NamingContainer);
        int index = gridRow.RowIndex;
        string check = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text;



    }
```

In Check i get the value NULL I don't know why? Looking forward for help. Thanks

Comment: I forget to mention one thing the Grid View is bind Dynamically from server side.

Answer (score 2):

```
TextBox txt = (TextBox)gridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("id");
string test = txt.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your GridTemplate and try

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
 ItemTemplate>
<asp:Textbox id="txtId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'> </asp:Textbox>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TemplateField>

    GridViewRow row = sender.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    int rowidx = row.RowIndex;
    Textbox check = (TextBox) GridView1.Rows[row].Findcontrol("id");
```

Try this code

Comment: I get the row index thats not the problem. Problem arises when I try to access the data of the cells of that row it return me null

Comment: @jibranmusa: what is the control at indez 0 , is it textbox?

Comment: Use this Altered Code

Comment: @SenthilKumar: i think we need to get the check.Text to get the value in Textbox , please correct me if im wrong...

Comment: @SenthilKumar This is one part of my solution which you have suggested. But with RowIndex i need to get the data of first Cell at index 0 where Id is contained. How can I get it as GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text give me null

Comment: GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text it's wrong idea so you use findcontrol to get particular index value

Answer (score 1):

When I used following I am getting blank ("")

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Id") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

But following is returning value:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Actually my data gets bind dynamically from back end so can't use Bound Field i guess

Comment: yes i have found the solution Thanks a lot for your Precious Time i really appreciate that

Comment: thats gr8 .. can you please share your solution with us, that can help others. Thanks!

Comment: @musa have you used DataKeys?